# Very slow writes in Cassandra

Tags: database, nosql, cassandra, benchmarking

I'm newbie in NoSQL and Cassandara in particular. At the moment doing some benchmarking with Cassandra and experiencing very slow write throughput.

As it is said, Cassandra can perform hundreds of thousands of inserts per second, however I'm not observing this:
1) when I send 100 thousand inserts simultaneously via 8 CQL clients, then throughput is ~14470 inserts per seconds.
2) when I do the same via 8 Thrift clients, then throughput is ~16300 inserts per seconds.

*I think Cassandra performance can be improved, but I don't know what to tune. Please take a look at the test conditions below and advise something. Thank you.*

**Tests conditions:**

*1.* Cassandra cluster is deployed on three machines, each machine has 8 cores Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5420  @ 2.50GHz, RAM is 16GB, network speed is 1000Mb/s.

*2.* The data sample is*

```
set MM[utf8('1:exc_source_algo:20100105000000.000000:ENTER:0')]['order_id'] = '1.0';
set MM[utf8('1:exc_source_algo:20100105000000.000000:ENTER:0')]['security'] = 'AA1';
set MM[utf8('1:exc_source_algo:20100105000000.000000:ENTER:0')]['price'] = '47.1';
set MM[utf8('1:exc_source_algo:20100105000000.000000:ENTER:0')]['volume'] = '300.0';
set MM[utf8('1:exc_source_algo:20100105000000.000000:ENTER:0')]['se'] = '1';
set MM[utf8('2:exc_source_algo:20100105000000.000000:ENTER:0')]['order_id'] = '2.0';
set MM[utf8('2:exc_source_algo:20100105000000.000000:ENTER:0')]['security'] = 'AA1';
set MM[utf8('2:exc_source_algo:20100105000000.000000:ENTER:0')]['price'] = '44.89';
set MM[utf8('2:exc_source_algo:20100105000000.000000:ENTER:0')]['volume'] = '310.0';
set MM[utf8('2:exc_source_algo:20100105000000.000000:ENTER:0')]['se'] = '1';
set MM[utf8('3:exc_source_algo:20100105000000.000000:ENTER:0')]['order_id'] = '3.0';
set MM[utf8('3:exc_source_algo:20100105000000.000000:ENTER:0')]['security'] = 'AA2';
set MM[utf8('3:exc_source_algo:20100105000000.000000:ENTER:0')]['price'] = '0.35';
```

*3.* Commit log is written the on local hard drive, the data is written on Lustre.

*4.* Keyspace description

```
Keyspace: MD:
  Replication Strategy: org.apache.cassandra.locator.NetworkTopologyStrategy
  Durable Writes: true
    Options: [datacenter1:1]
  Column Families:
    ColumnFamily: MM
      Key Validation Class: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BytesType
      Default column value validator: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BytesType
      Columns sorted by: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BytesType
      Row cache size / save period in seconds: 0.0/0
      Key cache size / save period in seconds: 200000.0/14400
      Memtable thresholds: 2.3249999999999997/1440/496 (millions of ops/minutes/MB)
      GC grace seconds: 864000
      Compaction min/max thresholds: 4/32
      Read repair chance: 1.0
      Replicate on write: true
      Built indexes: []
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using 8 threads/processes to do writes?  If each write takes 0.5 ms, then 8 threads/processes can only do 16,000 writes per second.

Comment: Yes, I'm using three simultaneous python scripts doing writes. You mean it the limitation? Or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: If you had 1 thread/process doing actions sequentially, and each action took 100 ms, you could only do 10 ops a second, and 2 threads could do 20 ops a second.  Using 3 threads, if you want to get 100k operations a second, each operation would have to complete in 0.03 ms.  This lack of client side parallelism may be your limitation.  Other things to check are the load on the server (both disk and cpu).

Answer (score 2):

Especially with python clients, you may see better performance by running each client as a separate process rather than thread, due to the global interpreter lock.

After that, try splitting the clients onto multiple machines if possible.

Also, make sure your clients are contacting all three nodes so the workload is evenly spread.

Writing data to Lustre, rather than local disk, might be a factor but I don't have experience with Lustre to tell.

Comment: Agreed, the big problem here is Lustre (as Adrian mentioned when Evgeny asked the same question on the Cassandra mailing list -- http://www.mail-archive.com/user@cassandra.apache.org/msg18328.html), and you may well need multiple machines to max out a 3-node Cassandra cluster from Python.